# PHP Laravel - How to use xSQL FUNC in model?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use MySQL FUNC `UUID()` in the SQL is similar to this :

```
INSERT INTO users SET user_guid=UUID();
```

I know laravel has model when I create an user and add it to DB, I can do this :

```
$user = new User;
$user->user_guid = uniqid();
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->email = Input::get('email');
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
$user->save();
```

If I want to use MySQL FUNC UUID replace uniqid(), what can I do for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DB::raw()`:

```
$user->user_guid = DB::raw('UUID()');
```